# Need guidance on e-commerce product developement

Tags: web, e-commerce, crm

I'm developing an e-commerce product. I need guidance to develop it. Is  there any article or book I can follow to develop it in a better way? Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way SO works. If you have code which causes problems you can come back. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue 3 years ago.
I started a platform from scratch, using just open source tools, like spring, hibernate, struts2, etc....
I can assure you, that it is realy time consuming, comparing to using Magento, or another e-commerce framework.
The good part is that you will have full knowledge of your code, and you can plug-in anything you need.
So, you have to decide, what´s best for you, regarding time, flexibility, etc.
You can find on the web, good tutorials, regarding database structure for e-commerce. I suggest starting from the database, and them you start the dev.
Regards